# JS - Set this To Main Parent

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code:

```js
module.exports = {
  on(event, callback) {
    callback();
  },
  PLAYER_ACTION: {
    SEND_MESSAGE(message) {
      console.log(this);
    },
  },
};
```

But when I `console.log` this in the `SEND_MESSAGE` function it returns

```js
{ SEND_MESSAGE: [Function: SEND_MESSAGE] }
```

How do I set `this` to the values of `module.exports`?

Answer (score 0):

After learning more about `this` and reading more articles,  I concluded it was not possible and instead used `module.exports` instead of `this`